# Laravel Cron Jobs - controller function

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduling

I have a controller in laravel project in /app/Http/Controllers.
The controller called transferDataController.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
class TransferDataController extends Controller{
public function moveStTempSales(){



 // then a lot of queries.

  }
}
```

I need to call this function every 15 minutes. Without calling the api using url on a button or some elements. I was reading about Laravel Schedule.
It works on Laravel 4? And if yes how can I schedule this function in my case ? 
I have a good knowledge in server cron jobs.

Comment: I'd say it's bad practice to put too much logic in a controller action. Move it to a library class function and then you can call the same function both from a controller and from a CLI command and then run that CLI command from a cron. I'm not sure if the scheduler is available in L4

Comment: If refactoring is not an option you could always add a `curl http://host/TransferData/moveStTempSales` to your cron tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go the following directory:

**yourproject/app/Console/Commands**

In this folder create you can create a class file that contains the function which is to be called on cron.

Now on the same path there is a file : **Kernel.php**

This file contains:

```
$schedule->command();
```

which is to be used to call the function of the currently created class.

After that use:

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

to run the functionality.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling)

Comment: yes understood. Is there any way to keep the function in my controller and call it in the schedule ?

Comment: @ElioChamy: I don't think so.

Comment: I tried a function in the kernel.php then php artisan schedule:run now working fine, thank you

Comment: Sounds great :)

Comment: Please one more question, I tried to delete a row in a table using the schedule every 1 minute, ->everyMinute(); when I run the schedule using php artian schedule:run it's working. I tried to add the row again, and after minutes It's not deleted, I have to run the schedule again.. any help ?

Comment: Put the schedule on cron job